Showing that the inclusion of the 2-skeleton of a simplicial complex induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups
Suppose that $K$ is a simplicial complex and let $K_{(2)}$ denote its 2-skeleton.
Show that that for all $x \in |K_{(2)}|$ the map
$i_*: \pi_1(|K_{(2)}|,x) \to \pi_2(|K|,x)$ induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups.
There are some solutions on this site but I believe that they are mostly incorrect or not fully explained.
In particular I am trying to show that this map is injective, namely that loops in the 2-skeleton which are homotopic in the whole polyhedron are homotopic within the 2-skeleton.
The typical solution I have found on this site is as follows:
"Suppose we have a homotopy $H: I \times I \to |K|$ between the loops in question. Then we can simplicially approximate $H$ to get $G: I \times I \to |K_{(2)}|$ agreeing with $H$ on the boundary of the square so we get a homotopy between the loops taking place in the 2-skeleton".
However, I do not see why we know that $G$ must agree with $H$ on the boundary of the square, or even that $G$ restricted to the sides of square are loops which are homotopic to the original ones in $|K_{(2)}|$ as opposed to $|K|$.
The simplicial approximation theorem at best can arrange that $G$ agrees with $H$ on the corners of the square, and that $G$ is homotopic to $H$ in $|K|$ so the sides of $G$ are too.
Both of these are too weak to reach the required conclusion.

A few comments: first, the title is inaccurate, since you're not asking about homology. Second, your proposed map in the second paragraph should go to $\pi_1$, not $\pi_2$, and it should go from $K_{(2)}$ to $K$, not the other direction. Third, the edge-path group should give you what you want.

Apologies yes the title is a typo. I have corrected it. I am unfamiliar with edge path groups as my course does not explicitly mention it. Is there a good reference for using this to approach the question in my context?

Wikipedia isn't bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group#Edge-path_group_of_a_simplicial_complex

Also, I edited my comment perhaps after you had read the first version, so I will repeat this part: your proposed map in the second paragraph should go to $\pi_1$, not $\pi_2$, and it should go from $K_{(2)}$ to $K$, not the other direction.

If all you're out for is a proof, you could view $K$ as a CW-complex instead and cite the respective result for CW-complexes (e.g. Hatcher Cor. 4.12).

First of all, we should assume (wlog) that $x$ is a vertex of $K$. I don't know if the result follows quite as stated in the quote you provide, but there is a way (not sure if it's the intended way) to get there using simplicial approximation.
First, suppose $L$ is a finite simplicial complex, $K$ a simplicial complex and $f\colon|L|\rightarrow|K|$ a map. Then for $n\gg0$, there is a simplicial map $g\colon L^{(n)}\rightarrow K$ s.t. $f\simeq|g|$. The usual proof of the simplicial approximation theorem shows that for $n\gg0$, every open star of $L^{(n)}$ maps under $f$ into an open star of $K$ and that if $g\colon(L^{(n)})_{0}\rightarrow K_0$ is any map on vertices s.t. $f(st(v,L^{(n)}))\subseteq st(g(v),K)$ for all vertices $v$ of $L^{(n)}$, then $g$ is a simplicial map that approximates $f$. In particular, $f\simeq|g|$ via a straight-line homotopy.
Now, we need two additional observations. First, if $L^{\prime}\subseteq L$ is a subcomplex s.t. $f(|L^{\prime}|)\subseteq|K_0|$, then $f\simeq|g|$ rel $|L^{\prime}|$. Indeed, every vertex $v$ of the induced subdivision $(L^{\prime})^{(n)}$ maps under $f$ to a vertex of $K$ and the only star containing that vertex is its own star, hence $f(v)=g(v)$. Now, any simplex of $(L^{\prime})^{(n)}$ gets mapped by $f$ to a vertex of $K$ (since the set of vertices is discrete) and the same holds for $g$ by affine linearity. Thus, $f\vert_{|L^{\prime}|}=|g|\vert_{|L^{\prime}|}$ and the straight-line homotopy is constant on $|L^{\prime}|$.
Next, if $L^{\prime\prime}\subseteq L$ and $K^{\prime}\subseteq K$ are subcomplexes s.t. $f(|L^{\prime\prime}|)\subseteq|K^{\prime}|$, then the restricted homotopy $f\vert_{|L^{\prime\prime}|}\simeq|g|\vert_{|L^{\prime\prime}|}$ takes place in $|K^{\prime}|$. Indeed, for any $x\in|L^{\prime\prime}|$, $f(x)\in|K^{\prime}|$, hence the carrier of $f(x)$ is a cell of $K^{\prime}$ and thus the straight-line homotopy takes $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ within $K^{\prime}$.
Now, let $H\colon I\times I\rightarrow|K|$ be a homotopy between two closed paths $I\rightarrow|K_2|$ in the $2$-skeleton. This is homotopic to a map $H^{\prime}\colon I\times I\rightarrow|K_2|$ that is simplicial w.r.t some subdivision of $I\times I$. Now, $H$ takes the subcomplex $\partial I\times I$ to the vertex $x$ of $K$, so the homotopy of homotopies $H\simeq H^{\prime}$ is rel $\partial I\times I$ by the first observation and, in particular, $H^{\prime}$ takes $\partial I\times I$ to $x$, hence is a homotopy of closed paths in $|K_2|$. Furthermore, $H(I\times\partial I)\subseteq|K_2|$, hence $H\vert_{I\times\partial I}\simeq H^{\prime}\vert_{I\times\partial I}$ in $|K_2|$ (and still rel $\partial I\times\partial I$) by the second observation. In total, we have that $H\vert_{I\times\{0\}}\simeq H^{\prime}\vert_{I\times\{0\}}\simeq H^{\prime}\vert_{I\times\{1\}}\simeq H\vert_{I\times\{1\}}$ as closed paths in $|K_2|$, as desired. (If you picture the homotopy of homotopies as a map on the cube $I^3$, then this homotopy is the result of composing three of that cube's faces.)

Aha. The version of the simplicial approximation theorem in my lecture notes merely guaranteed that if $L'$  was a subcomplex of $L$ with $f|{V{L'}} : V_{L'} \to V_K$ already simplicial, we could arrange that $f \simeq |g|$ rel $V_{L'}$. This is too weak for the quoted argument to be made to work. The two observations allow this to be upgraded to something that does the job here. I suspect an argument like this is along the lines of what the question was asking for.

@JohnRobertson That makes sense. For what it's worth, my "first observation" can be replaced with the version of simplicial approximation you have if we use instead of $I\times I$ the space $I\times I/\sim$, where the left and right edge are collapsed to a point (this can still be realized as a simplicial complex). I also think that the quoted argument works if you're willing to appeal to a "relative" version of the simplicial approximation theorem, but I believe (not confidently) that any version of that theorem that is strong enough to make this work is significantly harder to prove.

If I understand this question correctly, you are trying to show that the fundamental group of $K$ is completely determined by its 2-skeleton $K^{(2)}$. This can be proven using the Van Kampen Theorem, which describes how the fundamental group of a space $X\cup Y$ is related to the fundamental group of the constituent spaces $X$ and $Y$. You can show this inductively, by showing what happens when you add a tetrahedron to $K^{(2)}$. Hint: the sphere $S^n$ is simply connected for $n\geq2$.

Annoyingly the exercise wants me to do it using simplicial approximation of homotopies of paths and had another part asking for a proof via SvK. This is probably the nicest approach though.

Armstrong's Basic Topology Chapter 6.4 has a proof that $E(K,v)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1 (|K|,v)$ in the obvious way. This proof is mostly along the lines of a simplicial approximation argument I was looking for. It can be seen to also imply the result requested.
(As an aside, this approach is also nice because $E(|K|,v)$ has a nice interpretation in terms of the first homology group - we can deduce that paths along 1-simplices that are homotopic in $|K|$ are equivalent in a combinatorial way).
